# benefits of map over for loop in terms of safety

Tags: javascript

I have a vague understanding of what does it mean "provide immutability" when talking about using `map` over `for` loop. Because calling `Array.prototype.map` on array does not prevent you from altering original array. Let's say we have single threaded asynchronous program. In these circumstances is there an "immutability" benefit that `map` provides over `for` loop?

I can imagine the following code:

```js
function A() {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    const anotherArr = arr.map((e, i) => {
        arr[i] = 'changed'
        // here goes some asynchronous code
        return e * 2
    })
    // now arr is ['changed', 'changed', 'changed', 'changed', 'changed']
    // and anotherArr is [2, 3, 6, 8, 10]
}

function B() {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    const anotherArr = []
    for (let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        anotherArr[i] = arr[i] * 2
        arr[i] = 'changed'
        // here goes some asynchronous code
    }
    // and again:
    // now arr is ['changed', 'changed', 'changed', 'changed', 'changed']
    // and anotherArr is [2, 3, 6, 8, 10]
}
```

I guess that probably in function B `anotherArr` is created manually before populating. Therefore something in the same scope can alter it before `for` loop is completed. So my question is: "Is there a benefit of using `map` over `for` loop in single threaded asynchronous environment in terms of safety"?

**Editing**

I rephrase my question: "Is there some kind of immutability that `Array.prototype.map` function
provides (because it belongs to functional paradigm)".
As I understand now the `map` function in javascript is not about immutability,
it is about hiding some implementation details (how resulting array is constructed).
So `map` function is a delclarative way of doing things. `for` loop is an imperative
way of doing things (which brings more freedom and more responsibility I guess).

Comment: You are mutating original in both cases when you do `arr[i] = 'changed'`

Comment: No, the difference between `map` and a for loop with `push` isn’t safety. Mostly readability.

Answer (score -1):

map, reduce, filter, forEach, etc.

Methods above, in my mind, is nice for FP(functional programming).

Of course, you can use them instead of normal for loop, 
but normal for loop is faster than them(https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7).

So in my idea, if your don't care performance, use map, reduce, etc. is elegant and will get lesser and more readable code.